# Probability of serial numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What are the odds of getting a dollar bill with an 8 digit serial number where 3 of the numbers are the same?

Comment: exactly 3 of the numbers must be the same, or at least 3 ?

Comment: If the total number of bills is $\ll 10^8$ and they are issued sequentially dstarting from 00000001, the probability is extremely high.

Comment: Just a heads up a lot of people will give you wrong answers to this, which will fail to take account of Benford's law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law.  This actually makes it a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The number of combinations in which at least three digits are the same, equals the number of all combinations minus the ones where at most two digits are the same. We can consider five cases:

1. No double digits: ${10 \choose 8}8!$ options;
2. One double digit, six single ones: ${10 \choose 1} {8 \choose 2} {9 \choose 6} 6!$ options;
3. Two double digits, four single ones: ${10 \choose 2} {8 \choose 2, 2} {8 \choose 4} 4!$ options;
4. Three double digit, two single ones: ${10 \choose 3} {8 \choose 2, 2, 2} {7 \choose 2} 2!$ options;
5. Four double digits: ${10 \choose 4} {8 \choose 2, 2, 2, 2}$ options.

As such, the number of combinations in which at least three digits are the same, equals:

$$10^8 - {10 \choose 8}8! - {10 \choose 1} {8 \choose 2} {9 \choose 6} 6! - {10 \choose 2} {8 \choose 2, 2} {8 \choose 4} 4! - {10 \choose 3} {8 \choose 2, 2, 2} {7 \choose 2} 2! - {10 \choose 4} {8 \choose 2, 2, 2, 2} = 36,269,200$$

**Assuming that all $10^8$ bills are used**, the probability of getting a dollar bill with a serial number with at least three similar digits equals:

$$\frac{36,269,200}{100,000,000} \approx 0.3627$$

Comment: can you explain why for item#1 you multiple by 8!? shouldn't it be (10,8)? I think I'm missing this part. Thank you!

Comment: @adhg If you want every digit to occur exactly once, you can first select the 8 digits you are going to use, and then put them in a certain order. There are ${10 \choose 8}$ ways to choose these digits, and $8!$ ways to order them, for a total of $\frac{10 \cdot 9}{2} \cdot 8! = \frac{10!}{2}$ valid combinations. You can also look at it this way: there are 10 options for the first digit, 9 for the second, 8 for the third, ..., and 3 for the last one. As such, there are $10 \cdot 9 \cdot \cdots \cdot 3 = \frac{10!}{2}$ possible combinations.

Comment: got it make sense. Thanks

Comment: thanks for this - I think I was getting confused by the question.

Comment: @CarltonJohnson My pleasure, and welcome at MathSE. If this or any other answer was of help to you, please consider upvoting/accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we want *at least* three digits to be identical.

I cannot think about anything faster than that:

$A_3$=number of ways to have exactly 3 ones $=\binom{8}{3}*9^5$

$A_{33}$=number of ways to have exactly 3 ones and 3 twos $=\binom{8}
{3}\binom{6}{3}*8^2$

$A_4$=number of ways to have exactly 4 ones $=\binom{8}{4}*9^4$

$A_{43}$=number of ways to have exactly 4 ones and 3 twos $=\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{3}*8$

$A_{44}$=number of ways to have exactly 4 ones and 4 twos $=\binom{8}{4}$

$A_5$=number of ways to have exactly 5 ones $=\binom{8}{5}*9^3$

$A_{53}$=number of ways to have exactly 5 ones ans 3 twos $=\binom{8}{5}$

$A_6$=number of ways to have exactly 6 ones $=\binom{8}{6}*9^2$

$A_7$=number of ways to have exactly 7 ones $=\binom{8}{7}*9$

$A_8$=number of ways to have exactly 8 ones $=1$

Then the answer will be $10(A_3+A_4+A_5+A_6+A_7+A_8)-\binom{10}{2}(A_{33}+A_{43}+A_{44}+A_{53})$